# How to design a class for managing file path?

Tags: oop

In my app, I generate some xml file for instance : "/xml/product/123.xml" where 123 is the product's id and 123.xml contains informations about this product. I also have "/xml/customer/123.xml" where 123.xml contains informations about the client ... 123

How can I manage these file paths :

1. I create the file path directly in the serialization method ?
2. I create 2 static classes : CustomerSerializationPathManager and ProductSerializationPathManager with 1 method : getPath(int customerID) and getPath(int productID)
3. I create one static class : SerializationPathManager with 2 methods : getCustomerPath(int customerID) and getProductPath(int productID)
4. Something else

I'd prefer solution 3 because if I think there's only one reason to change this class : I change the root directory.

So I'd like to have your thoughts about it... thx

Comment: Why do you need to manage the file path when generating the files? You'll get better answers if you specify the reason.

Comment: because I save data about my product and my customer in xml file ... Why I do that ? Because my web designer prefer xslt to anything else for displaying the informations.

Comment: So you need this data in specific folder location? You just want to manage the location where you save the XMLs?

Comment: I just need to manage the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save the files in specific folders and the location of these files can change, then you should move this information in a configuration file and later use if from there.

You then create a class similar to a factory, with `getPathForProductExports`, `getPathForCustomerExports` etc which reads the configuration file to return the desired path.

The configuration file can be a simple .properties file:

```
customer_path=/xml/customer/
product_path=/xml/product/
```

When generating the XML (be it customer, product or whatever) you prepend the appropriate path (`getPathForCustomerExports`, `getPathForProductExports`) to the file name.

If you later change the location you just edit the config file.

Comment: my only problem with this solution is that I'll see a string ".xml" in my saving method, so my saving method will still have responsibility for serialization and create file path 'even if it's only a part of it), but I may be wrong.

Comment: You are not wrong. My answer is incomplete because it does not ensure a proper separation of concerns between the classes. The solution would be to go with your number 3. Put all the data likely to change in the config file (this will allow you to change the locations without touching the code) and then, the SerializationPathManager will encapsulate ALL access to the parameters and ONLY EXPOSE THE TWO METHODS: getCustomerPath(customerID) and getProductPath(productID). An ID goes in and the proper path goes out and nobody knows about any file path or extension except SerializationPathManager.